# ionic build error code 137

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to build my app for android. It built fine for the first time but there were some typos in first so i edited the html and now i am trying to build the app. It is giving an error with exit status 137. the nodejs is latest so is the npm. I have checked the memory approx 700mb available. 
New to ionic so now i cannot figure out the mistake.
Also rebuilded the node-sass. Nothing is working.
it takes too much time after sass started and then gets killed automatically.

Attaching the debug file

```
14 verbose stack Exit status 137
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid ionic-hello-world@
16 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/files/ic2017app
17 verbose Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
18 verbose argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:build" "--" "--v2"
19 verbose node v6.10.1
20 verbose npm  v4.4.4
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 137
23 error ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build: `ionic-app-scripts build "--v2"`
23 error Exit status 137
24 error Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build script 'ionic-app-scripts build "--v2"'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     ionic-app-scripts build "--v2"
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 137, true ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

700 mb is not enough. Recheck again. It must will be a memory overflow error.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Spent a day trying to figure out why my test VPS environment couldn't build and then ran `free -hl` during the build after reading this comment. My build had chewed through all the RAM and swap space!